# VB.net -- converting datatypes originating from xml file

Tags: vb.net, types, type-conversion

datatype hell here...
I have succesfully called xml info from the web, only to not be able to change the type to something I can use...

here's part of the code :

```
    Dim fxs As String
    Dim fx As Double
    m_xmld = New Xml.XmlDocument()
    m_xmld.Load("http://rss.timegenie.com/forex.xml")
    m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("forex/data")
    i = 0
    For Each m_node In m_nodelist
        fxs = Convert.ToString(m_node.Item("rate").InnerText)
        fx = CDbl(fxs)
```

the rest of the code is not relevant, but here's my problem:
the "rate" comes in in the form of 4.047492763
I first tried to convert it to double, but then I get a null
then I tried to convert it to a string, which works, but when I try to convert the string to a double, I get 4047492763 - the decimal point seems to have disappeared.

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the computer on which your code is running has the locale set to one which uses a full stop as the thousands separator. The remarks in the [documentation for CDbl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) states:

> **Culture Sensitivity**. The type conversion functions involving strings perform conversions based on the current culture settings for the application.

So you need to parse the string using a culture which uses a full stop as the decimal separator, like [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can specify the culture to use in parsing by using the [Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx) method:

```
fx = Double.Parse(m_node.Item("rate").InnerText, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

However, as you appear to be dealing with currency, it might be better to use the [Decimal data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), i.e. use `Decimal.Parse` instead of `Double.Parse`.